# Batch File - Syntax Incorrect (Going inside a directory)

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, cmd

I am writing a batch script to go inside a folder  if it exists do a certain thing if its not do other

I have the hierarchy as follows :-

```
  C:\Validation\docs\chm\help.chw
```

I want to go to this 'help.chw' file this is what i am doing and getting the error

```
IF EXIST docs (
CD docs echo curr dir = %CD% goto imagefolder 
) 

IF EXIST docs (
CD docs echo curr dir = %CD% goto imagefolder 
) 

ECHO Please include 'docs' folder in the current working directory
ECHO.
ECHO The program would close now , restart the batch file after making the changes cited above
ECHO.
goto exit
```

This is what i wrote

```
 IF EXIST docs (
 CD "docs"
 echo curr dir = %CD%
 goto imagefolder
```

)

it gives

```
 C:\Validation MSI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `cd` to `docs echo curr dir = %CD% goto imagefolder` which is obviously not going to work.

Put a line between `cd` and the other commands.

```
IF EXIST docs (
CD docs
echo curr dir = %CD%
goto imagefolder 
) else (
echo Folder not found
)

IF EXIST docs (
CD docs
echo curr dir = %CD%
goto imagefolder 
) else (
echo Folder not found
)
```

I put your `goto` lines on a separate line as well, as I am presuming they aren't part of the message to `echo`.

***Update***

The reason your code isn't echoing the actual current directory is because the `cd` variable is inside `if` parentheses, which means that any variables inside are evaluated at runtime, so if they change before the brackets have ended, the value will be the same as it was before the brackets, in this case - the parent directory.

The fix is to enable delayed expansion, which will evalutate them when it gets to them, rather than evaluate the while block at once.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
IF EXIST docs (
cd docs
echo curr dir = !CD!
goto imagefolder
)
```

Comment: What do you mean the else part?

Comment: I mean if certain folder is not found then there is an message echod

Comment: ok i seem to write some thing wrong in here after going to 'docs' i echoed the path and i got  C:\Validation now i want to have the path as C:\Validation MSI\docs

Comment: You will need to quote the path, try `cd "docs"` or whatever folder it is instead.

Comment: Actually, that won't matter, cd doesn't need quotes. Can you post what you are using that outputs C:\Validation.